# Navigation Drawer available at a particular activity, not the launching screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, manifest

I built a navigation drawer and it works fine, but I want it to be available at a particular activity, not on the launching activity. I think I need to write something in the Manifest?

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NavDrawerActivity"
            android:label="test"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FirebaseAuth" />
        <activity android:name=".Results" />
        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Display" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So the `.Display` is my launching screen, and I want the `NavDrawer` to be on my `MainActivity` screen.

Comment: Just add it to that activity

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest you should have

```
<activity 
android:name=".Display"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light.DarActionBar">
</activity>
```

Also you have to implement the Navigation drawer for it to show

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

DrawerLayout drawer=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
};
```

Comment: These aren't working I'm afraid :/ Look, I have another normal menu in the .Display (launch screen) and I am just calling it from the Display class like so: 

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        //creating a menu item
        MenuInflater inflate = getMenuInflater();
        inflate.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

and works perfectly well.

Comment: Now for the NavDrawer, I have its class called NavDrawerActivity with the code it comes with, and the class MainActivity which I need to place the NavDrawer in. But typing this code:
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu navMenu) {
            MenuInflater inflate = getMenuInflater();
            inflate.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, navMenu);
            return true;
        }
doesn't make the drawer show up.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. All I had to do was transfer all my contents from the activity_main.xml, to the content_main.xml, and all the code in .MainActivityClass to the .NavDrawerActivity class.